# Invisible Mouse Cursor on startup on 14.04 [SOLVED]

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cursor

My mouse cursor won't appear on startup unless I restart lightdm. But when I reboot cursor doesn't appear.

I tried the setting below:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

then tried reinstalling the `lightdm` and also changing `cursor-theme`.

I also tried installing Nvidia drivers from *Additional drivers* but it causes booting to black screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Nvidia drivers should be fixed first. [Follow this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Installation_without_X_.2F_from_the_console), while you [boot your system with `nomodeset` kernel option](https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/6341).

If you will still have problems with the cursor, feel free reporting back!

Comment: After i installed Ubuntu 16.04, i followed the guide and installed the NVIDIA drivers successfully. I have no problems now. Thank you !

Comment: @JamCry Glad to hear it's working. Feel free to mark antivirtel's answer as "accepted" by clicking on the gray checkmark next to it -- that way antiveritel will receive points for answering your question, and other people will know you're all set with your issue.